# How to add custom font css dynamically in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am adding fonts to ckeditor dynamically. Names are adding to fonts but not their CSS. 
Function for getting CSS :

```
function getcss(){
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url : "/demoProject/fonts/fontStyle",
        async:false,
        success : function(response) {
            data = response;
//              CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = response;
        },
        error : function(response) {
            displayError("Error while getting fonts.");
        },
    });
    console.log("return :" + data);
    return data;
}
```

Function for adding font names and style :

```
    $.ajax({
            url : "/demoProject/fonts/getFonts",
            success : function(response) {
                CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = getcss();
                $.each(response, function(index, item ) {
                    var font_Name = item.name;

                    CKEDITOR.config.font_names = font_Name +'/'+font_Name + ';' + CKEDITOR.config.font_names;
                });
    });
```

CSS from database :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'windsong';
    src:  url('../fonts/Tue_Jul_28_09:31:29_IST_2015windsong-webfont.eot');
    src:  url('../fonts/Tue_Jul_28_09:31:29_IST_2015windsong-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Decoration';
    src:  url('../fonts/Tue_Jul_28_13:23:32_IST_2015windsong-webfont.eot');
    src:  url('../fonts/Tue_Jul_28_13:23:32_IST_2015windsong-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
}
```

I have tried may things but not getting any resourceful result.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any suitable solution for this. So i make an alternative that rather than adding font to css statically i made a file dynamically and write font-face in that file. After creating css gave path of that file in `CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss ='pathof/dynamic/genrated/file.css';`